# How do I edit arguments within back-ticks in php?

Tags: php, python, apache, shell, arguments

so what I am trying to do is utilize the backtick operator in php to run some python code that will display on my Apache Localhost. This python code contains the ability to edit arguments, but when I tried to edit the arguments, nothing came out on my localhost website.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload your files</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <p>Upload your file</p>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></input><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<?PHP
  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    $path = "uploads/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
      echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
      " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
  }
?>
<?PHP 
   $python = `python classify_image.py --image_file C:\xampp\htdocs\uploads\bamboo.jpg`;
   echo $python;
?>
```

This is what I see in Localhost: 
[image: With the modified argument]

But when I remove the " --image_file C:\xampp\htdocs\uploads\bamboo.jpg" from the backticks, the python code reverts to reading the default image and returns this on my localhost:
[image: Without the modified argument]

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my use of the backtick operator in php?

Comment: have you tried `exec()` etc ?

Comment: What do you mean by "edit arguments"? Since you're running it in the webserver, it can't prompt for input from the user.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not looking for input from the user. Right now, I just want to make sure the backticks work in the sense that I can change what the input for the python file is. Editing arguments would change the input.

Comment: You can put a variable in there: `--image-file 'C:/xampp/htdocs/$path'`

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks for telling me this, but my main problem is the fact that my python code appears to not return anything after I add the --image-file part in the the backticks.

Comment: @rtfm does exec() have the same syntax as the backticks?

Comment: well you could ask me or read ->>>> http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable inside the backticks.

You should also put the `classify_image.py` call inside the `if`, so you only do it when the file has been successfully uploaded.

And use forward slashes in the pathname rather than backslashes, or double the backslashes. In double quotes and backticks, backslash is an escape prefix, resulting in incorrect parsing of the pathname.

```
<?PHP
  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    $path = "uploads/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
      echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
      " has been uploaded";
      $python = `python classify_image.py --image_file C:/xampp/htdocs/$path`;
      echo $python;
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
  }
?>
```